# Apache POI Remove Revision Password

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When creating an Excel workbook based on an existing Workbook that has both an open password and a revision password, I am seemingly unable to remove the revision password.

```java
 try(Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputPath.toFile(), "my-password") {
  // make some changes

  ((XSSFWorkbook)wb).setWorkbookPassword(null, null);
  ((XSSFWorkbook)wb).setRevisionsPassword(null, null);

  try(OutpuStream os = Files.newOutputStream(outputPath)) {
    wb.write(os);
  }

}
```

When opening the newly created workbook, the main password is removed, but I am still prompted to enter a password to modify the file: `WorkbookXYZ.xlsx is reserved by...`

How can I effectively remove the revision password?  I am wondering if this is Mac OS related and maybe Excel for Mac is storing the password differently than expected.

I have also tried:

```java
 wb.unLock();
 wb.unLockStructure();
 wb.unLockRevision();
 wb.unLockWindows();
```

Without any luck. Additionally, I tried *setting* a new password, but the file still seems to use the old password.

I am using:

1. Java 8
2. Microsoft Excel for Mac 16.62
3. Apache POI & POI OOXML 5.2.2

Answer (score 2):

Seems the revisions password is not what you think it is.

Workbook protection consists of encryption using algorithm, salt and password. The encryption password is not stored in the encrypted file.

On Workbook-level you can lock the structure of your workbook by specifying a password. This is the workbook password. Additional revisioning tracking can be set and additional protected with a password. This is the revisions password. Both is contained in workbook protection settings which get removed by `XSSFWorkbook.unLock`.

The setting read-only recommended and the password for this is a setting in file-sharing settings of the workbook. Changing this is not provided by `apache poi` up to now. This can only be set using the underlying class `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook`.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

import java.io.*;

class ExcelRemoveAllPasswords {
 
 static void unsetFileSharing(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {    
  CTWorkbook ctWorkbook = workbook.getCTWorkbook();
  CTFileSharing ctfilesharing = ctWorkbook.getFileSharing();
  if (ctfilesharing != null) {
   ctWorkbook.unsetFileSharing();
  }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  String sourceFilePath = "./sourceFile.xlsx";
  String resultFilePath = "./resultFile.xlsx";
  String encryptionPasswd = "passwd";
  
  try ( FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFilePath);  
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(in, encryptionPasswd);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(resultFilePath); ) {
  
   if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
    XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook)workbook;
    xssfWorkbook.unLock(); // this removes the whole workbookProtection including workbook and revisions password
    unsetFileSharing(xssfWorkbook); // this unset the fileSharing settings including read only recommended and password 
   }

   workbook.write(out);
   workbook.close();
  }
 }
}
```

There are confusing terms here used by Microsoft and Apache POI.

[Protection and security in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protection-and-security-in-excel-be0b34db-8cb6-44dd-a673-0b3e3475ac2d) tells what is possible.

---

**File encryption:** When you choose this option, you specify a password and lock the Excel file. This prevents other users from opening the file.

[Apache POI - Encryption support](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) describes how to encrypt and to decrypt. But using this, calling `setWorkbookPassword` is not necessary as this is done internally. The `WorkbookFactory` class provides a more convenient access to decryption only by passing a password to it's `create` method.

`XSSFWorkbook.unLock` removes all workbook protection settings. It can be used after decrypting to remove all workbook protection passwords too. But it will not remove the additional password to skip the read-only-recommendation as this is not contained in workbook protection settings but in file-sharing settings.

---

**Setting a password to open or modify a file:** You specify a password to open or modify a file. Use this option when you need to give Read-only or edit access to different users.

This is the additional password to skip the read-only-recommendation.

Apache POI does not provide direct access to that pasword. It gets stored in a `fileSharing` element in workbook's XML. It can be got from `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook` as I have shown in my answer.

---

**Workbook-level:** You can lock the structure of your workbook by specifying a password. Locking the workbook structure prevents other users from adding, moving, deleting, hiding, and renaming worksheets.

The password what Apache POI handles via `XSSFWorkbook.setWorkbookPassword` and `XSSFWorkbook.validateWorkbookPassword` gets used as the password for `XSSFWorkbook.lockStructure` and `XSSFWorkbook.lockWindows`.

---

The password which Apache POI tries to handle via `XSSFWorkbook.setRevisionsPassword` and `XSSFWorkbook.validateRevisionsPassword` is the password which was used in former Excel versions in the shared workbook feature. This feature is outdated. See [About the shared workbook feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534). So `XSSFWorkbook.lockRevision` will not work using current Excel versions anymore.

Comment: Got it, this removes the password for me, thanks! So just to confirm, if the "Password to Modify" isn't the Revision password...what is?

Comment: @aarbor: Tried to shed more light on this. See supplements in the answer.